# How to properly update npm peer dependencies?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm, package-managers

I have an npm package `A` which has a peer dependency on package `B`:

```
"peerDependencies": {
   "B": "^0.4.0",
}
```

I also have a Node.js project `C` which use `A` as a plain dependency.

Since I installed `A` in `C` with:

```
npm install A --save
```

This means I also have `B` installed as a peer dependency with the latest version which is compatible to 0.4.0.

What happens when a new minor version of `B` released? Let's say `B` 0.5.0 comes out.

This is still compatible to `A` (at least according to SemVer), so I don't want to update my package `B` because `B` should still work with 0.4.x. I don't want to restrict the users of my package `A` to use 0.5.0 from `B` just because I like using latest versions.

But in my own project `C` I'd still prefer to use the latest version of `B`.

What can I do?

I thought that

```
npm update B
```

should work (i.e. update peer dependency `B` to its latest version which is still compatible with my dependencies), but it does nothing.

Comment: What version of `npm` are you using?  The meaning of `peerDependencies` changed in v3.

Comment: I see that in npm v3 `peerDependencies` will not be automatically installed. In this case, solving the peer dependency update problem would be simple.

But since npm v3 is not released yet, I'd like to know how to solve this problem with npm 2.11.2 which I'm currently using.

Comment: if project `C` requires `B` then it should be a dependency to `C`. But on your case, it is you like latest `B`, so maybe you should keep as was. In real world, such case might happen when there is a security leak happens on `B` and the latest release comes out, but `A` is not released yet. I think you have to wait until `A` release a fix.